# Bluetooth won't connect after upgrade to 23.10

Tags: sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, pipewire

After upgrading to 23.10 from 22.04, I can't seem to actually connect to any of the bluetooth devices I was before. Presumably pipewire is what changed, but not sure.

Bluetooth settings say the device is paired, but the connection toggle just cycles on and off. If I go through Blueman and right click > Connect, I get an error message "br-connection-profile-unavailable".

I'm not familiar with pipewire before this, and not sure how to troubleshoot.

From pactl info:

```
Server String: /run/user/1001/pulse/native
Library Protocol Version: 35
Server Protocol Version: 35
Is Local: yes
Client Index: 386
Server Name: PulseAudio (on PipeWire 0.3.79)
Server Version: 15.0.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hmm, perhaps you are missing a dependency or two.
Suggest you install a lib. In terminal, enter command:

sudo apt install libspa-0.2-bluetooth

[ note: its description states: "This package contains a plugin to make Bluetooth audio devices such as speakers and headsets available to the PipeWire server'. ]

After install, restart your pc.

Comment: That solved it - strange that it wouldn't be included already...

Thank you!!!

Comment: This resolved my issue as well, although I didn’t need to restart my computer, `systemctl --user restart pipewire` did the trick.